# Spark Create a dataframe from an InputStream?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I want to avoid writing the entire stream to a file and then load it to dataframe. what's the right way?

Comment: spark streaming?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@textFile(path:String,minPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]

Comment: @Reactormonk, this API gets a path in hdfs, not a stream.

Comment: What's your `InputStream`?

Comment: A stream read from a remote server using REST API.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Spark Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations) and [sqlnetworkWordCount](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.1/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/SqlNetworkWordCount.scala) which explains that your problem can be solved by creating `singleton instance` of `SparkSession` by using `SparkContext` of `SparkStreaming`.

You should have better ideas by going through above links where `dataframes` are created from `streaming rdd`.